# Serilog properties on class level

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm trying to achieve something very simple, but seems hard to accomplish in C#. I cannot stress enough that the example below, is JUST an example. Sure, I can create the Warrior in a better way, but this is the setup I have right now and like answers regarding this setup.

I want to prefix the log messages of the Warrior class with the Name. The Serilog documentation and online examples all use log properties inside a using statement like this:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Name", _name))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("This warrior is doing some work ...");
}
```

But this is only valid/usable if your object has a short lifetime. The question is specifically asked for long lived objects. Warrior will have a long lifetime, and will have many more functions then only the one in this example. Also, this has NOTHING to do with HttpContext.

To recap, pretty simple question. I'd like to prefix the log in a certain class with the name value and this class will have a LONG lifetime.

In the example below, when setting the PushProperty, it will set it for the whole application, thus also for main. This is not desired. I'd only want the prefix for Warrior.

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly List<Warrior> _warriors = new List<Warrior>();
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithThreadId()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:
                "[{Level:u3} - {ThreadId}] {Name}: {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}")
            .CreateLogger();

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();

        while (true)
        {
            Log.Information("Create a new warrior. Enter the name: ");

            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            var warrior = new Warrior( host.Services
            .GetRequiredService<ILogger<Warrior>>(), name);
            _warriors.Add(warrior);
        }
    }
}

internal class Warrior
{
    private readonly ILogger<Warrior> _logger;
    private readonly string _name;

    public Warrior( 
        ILogger<Warrior> logger,
        string name)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _name = name;

        LogContext.PushProperty("Name", _name);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("This warrior is doing some work ...");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a logger for the same scope as your service and set the context property for that scope's logger only.

You could instantiate the Warrior class the following way:

```
//...
var logger = Log.ForContext<Warrior>();
var warrior = new Warrior(logger, name);
_warriors.Add(warrior);
//...
```

and use the logger in warrior like this:

```
public Warrior( 
    ILogger logger,
    string name)
{
    //...
    _logger = logger.ForContext("Name", _name);
    //...
}
```

Although this way you have to use Serilog's ILogger interface in your service.

Comment: Tried this,  but doesn't resolve the problem as the main function is still printing warrior names. Also, I'd like to use dependency injection.

Comment: @ArnoudVangrunderbeek You can use dependency injection, the warrior class still expects the logger from outside in his constructor. What do you mean by "the main funtion is still printing warrior names"?